# Regular expression for binary files

Tags: python, regex, binaryfiles, binary-data

How would you use regular expressions to parse through binary files?

What I have so far

```
import re

format = re.compile() <--

f.open("input.dat", "rb")

for line in f.readlines():
    data = re.search(format, line)
```

I'm not sure what to put inside compile as I am only used to writing regex for strings.

specifically I want so break down the format to be:

2 bytes, 2 bytes, 18 bytes

Comment: regexp is the wrong instrument for this. please consider Aif's solution with `unpack`

Answer (score 3):

If you know already the binary structure of the file, then [struct](https://python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/library/struct.html?highlight=struct) `unpack` is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand why you want to parse a binary file with a regex.

Are you saying you want to continually parse the bytes in 2-2-18 byte chunks? In that case, why not just read that many bytes as you go along using standard IO methods?